# Assigning values to Cplex variables

Tags: cplex

Recently I found that changing values of the variables in structure such as lower and upper bounds is time consuming process.

I am using Cplex to solve optimization of metabolic networks. Constraint in Cplex structure in MATLAB represent the reaction constraint in reaction. Now I wish to change these lower and upper bounds of constraints many times to analyze the metabolic networks. And it takes almost the same amount of time in changing the bounds as to solve the LP problem.

Please suggest any efficient ways to change to variables in multiple iterations.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the 'values' of variables? What are your 'multiple iterations' for? What are you trying to achieve? Give us more insight into your issues.